# Silent rewrite / redirect with subdomain .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have structure:

```
public/test1
public/test1/a
public/test1/b

public/test2
public/test2/a
public/test2/b
```

I want to rewrite / redirect as below:

```
test1.domain.com -> redirect to -> domain.com/test1 and user see -> test1.domain.com

test1.domain.com/a -> redirect to -> domain.com/test1/a and user see -> test1.domain.com/a

test2.domain.com -> redirect to -> domain.com/test2 and user see -> test2.domain.com

test2.domain.com/a -> redirect to -> domain.com/test2/a and user see -> test2.domain.com/a
```

All redirect / rewrite is silent. How can i solve it?

Comment: Please understand how this place works: we help, but you have to do the work yourself. We are _not_ here to do your work for you. That means: start yourself, read into the topic. Then, if you hit an issue you cannot solve yourself, _then_ is the time to come here and ask by posting your current attempt and pointing out the exact issue.

Comment: Are all three host names (you call them "subdomains") served by the same http server?

Answer (score 0):

If the host names are served by the same http server, then you can use internal rewriting capturing the first token of the requested host name by means of a condition:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.org$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /%1/$1 [END]
```

If you operate a really old version of the apache http server then you may have to replace the `END` flag with the `L` flag which should also work in this case. Try that if you run into an http status 500 (server internal error). You also definitely should monitor your http servers error log file in such a case.

If instead those two host names are *not* served by the same http server that serves the shorter domain name, then probably the best approach is to use the builtin proxy module to internally relay the requests to that server.

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: It's not work with me. It still redirect instead of keep original url.

Comment: Please make sure you _really_ emptied your browsers cache and retry.

Comment: The above code certainly will _not_ perform an external redirection. So the question is: what is different in your case? Do you see anything in your http servers error log file? What does the access log file show? What response do you see in the networking tab of your browsers development console?

Comment: With test1.domain.com -> result -> The requested URL /test1/test1/index.html was not found on this server.

Comment: RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /%1/$1 [END], i think it will duplicate subdomain. So i try with RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1 [END], it's work with url test1.domain.com/test1. It's not url i want and it's redirect

Comment: The above code does an internal rewriting to access file `/test1/a` in the document root of that http server. If that file exists is nothing I can answer. That code certainly does not do an external redirection. Also it certainly does not by itself somehow duplicate the subdomain. There has to be something else interfering here. You still did not answer my question of those host names are all served by the same http server. You did not supply information about the actual response you receive.

Comment: Sorry i miss information. All in same http server, same host name, same public directory